# Flutter desktop - plugin for windows

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

I am looking for help with the plugins in the flutter desktop. I am using https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding to develop the desktop app. Till I was using only the functions that come out of the box with the Flutter all was working fine. Now I have to implement a missing part (printing the file using the external printer). I am struggling because the examples in the github repositories do not give a full vision of how to do that. There is a `windows` directory where the code responsible for building the app for windows is. Now I do not know where I can put my code to start developing the code that I need. The windows directory looks like this:

[image: source tree]

Where can I put the code to register the Method Channel and the handle each function execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually trying to build a plugin, per the title of your question, you don't put your code anywhere in that directory; instead you would [create a plugin](https://flutter.dev/desktop#writing-a-plugin) and put the code there. Being separate from the application is what makes it a plugin.

If you just mean you want to add MethodChannel-based code directly to your native app, you can put the code wherever you like in that directory. As long as you don't break core assumptions like the name of the project or build settings used by Flutter the project is yours to do what you like with, just as with template-created Flutter projects targeting mobile platforms. You would just need to register the channel somewhere during your runner startup.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but the question is how to wire my newly prepared code (that handles MethodChannels executions) with the current base? For the windows (which I want to create the MethodCahnnel for) has `main.cpp` but there is no method skeleton that I have to override or whatever to register my new function to execute?

Comment: For the Android project, we use `new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler` and we should put this code into the `onCreate` of the FlutterActivity. Where to put this in the windows project?

Comment: The very end of my answer addresses that question; I'm not sure how to be more specific. Can you explain what exactly you're looking for beyond that? (Edit: updated that part of the answer to link to the line in question if that helps.)

Comment: Ok, I think that it would be better to go with the `example_plugin` and try to configure that with the help of readme. Unfortunately, the readme is not very helpful especially when it tells about going to `File` > `Add` > `Existing Project` but gives no info about the code editor that was used to write this readme. Is there a chance that you know what code editor was on the mind of the author of this description? @smorgan

Comment: As there is a early stage support for windows in flutter. I was just wondering that can we use dart_mssql plugin  into windows desktop app to fetch data. i know flutter desktop is still in early stage so it might  not support but just want to know if we can then how to do it. I tried to do that putting dll files in same directory and tried to just run it and it runs the app but not showing the screen. so if anyone can help with that it would be great help. Thanks.