# Flutter Desktop MACOS does anyone has an example for platform channel?

Tags: macos, flutter

im trying to do a platform channel to macos but cant find a proper example. The current documentation only has examples for android and ios [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). Ive googled it and seems from the github theres support. Can anyone clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Related question: [Flutter desktop - plugin for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58632322/295004)

Comment: [path_provider](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider) is a good example

Comment: @RichardHeap https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos/example/macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift is actually empty or not modified at all, so method channel wouldnt work?

Comment: @MorrisonChang i will try to look into making a plugin, i have never done one so i will look into the documentation and come back with a proper answer. Thank you.

Comment: That file is part of the example, so is correct. The plugin implementation is here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos/macos/Classes/PathProviderPlugin.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any plugin that supports macOS, such as [shared_preferences](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_macos/macos/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.swift) or [url_launcher](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_macos/macos/Classes/UrlLauncherPlugin.swift), is an example of using platform channels.

Also, the macOS channel APIs are shared with iOS, so the iOS example you linked to applies to macOS as well.

Comment: both your answer and @Richard Heap are correct. Thank you for clarifying..

Comment: @smorgan, I followed the iOS example, however, this line throws error on MacOS, `let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController` , the error in xcode is `Use of unresolved identifier 'window'`. Therefore, an example for MacOS would be great.

Comment: @skyred The answer you are replying to links to two different macOS examples.

Comment: @smorgan, the above two links are for plugins, They override `public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar)` , while the example of iOS in the original question overrides `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`, which is different from the function in `AppDelegate.swift` on MacOS. In MacOS's `AppDelegate.swift`, it overrides `func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication)`, and `windows` is unresolved there.

Comment: @skyred This question was about platform channels; the plugins I linked to both use platform channels. If you have a question that is not about platform channels, you should open a new question.

Comment: @smorgan, Thanks a lot for your answer. My question is exactly same as the original one. The official doc only covers building iOS **app** with platform channel, I would like to see one for MacOS **app** using platform channel.Your links are about building **plugins** using platform channel. They sounded same, and I wish them worked for me. But, they didn't.

Comment: The platform channel APIs (message channels, method channels, codecs, etc.)  are identical whether called from a plugin or directly in the application, so I don't understand what distinction you are making.

Answer (score 6):

The answer existed talked about channel usage building **plugins**, and I saw one example building macOS **apps** (not plugins, as there are some differences between them) with platform channel **here [on GitHub](https://github.com/tangs/idiom_lv_maker/blob/c50636c1de8a1cb437be60bde46a7b4fbb9859aa/macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift)**.

(I found this by searching codes with  `Channel applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_: NSApplication)` on GitHub)